# Typescript/Angular - undefined property- how to access variable in array

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2

I learned from debugging that q is undefined in the next() function. How can I get access to "id" in my array in order to push the value from a component(single.Value) to local storage? Thanks so much for any help you can offer!

```
 <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Quiz</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-left (click)="prev()"><ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon> Prev</button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-right (click)="next(q)">Next<ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content padding>
    <ion-slides #Quiz>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let q of questions">
    {{q.question}}
    <range [single]="single"></range>
      <progress-bar [progress]="loadProgress"></progress-bar>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>

Typescript file:

    export class QuizPage {
    public RangeComponent;
    public ProgressBar;

    single = {
    Value: 2
    };

    questions = [
    {id: "programming", question: 'Which programming language do you     prefer?'}

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage,     public rangeComponent: RangeComponent, public progressBar: ProgressBarComponent) {
    this.randomizeAnswers(this.questions);
    this.setData();
    this.getData();
    }


    randomizeAnswers(questions: any[]): any[] {
    for (let i = this.questions.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      let temp = this.questions[i];
      this.questions[i] = this.questions[j];
      this.questions[j] = temp;
    }

    return this.questions;
    }


    setData() {
    this.storage.set('QuestionData', this.questions);
    }

    getData() {
    this.storage.get('QuestionData').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    });
    }

    //slides
    @ViewChild('Quiz') Quiz: any;

    next(q) {
    // console.log('single.Value is next');
    console.log(this.single.Value);
    this.saveToArray(q);
    this.single.Value = 2;  //  Reset value to middle after every question
    this.Quiz.slideNext();
    this.progressBar.addProgress();
    }

    saveToArray(q) {
    if (q.id == "programming") {
      this.storage.set('programming', this.single.Value);
      this.storage.get('programming').then((data2) => {
        console.log("data logged.");
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q` is undefined in the `next()` function because you are using it outside of your `*ngFor`.

Instead of passing q into your next function you can use `this.Quiz.getActiveIndex()` to get the current position of your slider and then get the id from the questions array directly:

```
this.questions[this.Quiz.getActiveIndex()].id // check if the slide index starts at 0 or 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This was very helpful. Thank you!